# What's the meaning of 'breath curls towards her'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I am reading a book and there is a sentence

> My breath curls towards her, wet and ghostly, but no words follow.

I don't understand the meaning of "breath curls towards her".

What does that mean?

Comment: What book? Do you have a link? Author? Any details at all?

Answer (score 5):

When weather is cold enough, water vapour in the air you breathe out condenses and becomes visible as white mist. Hence "wet and ghostly".

http://thefreedictionary.com/curl :

> **curl**
>   *v. intr.*
>   1. To form ringlets or coils.
>   2. To assume a spiral or curved shape.
>   3. To move in a curve or spiral.

> My breath curls towards her, wet and ghostly, but no words follow

When narrator opened their mouth, they breathed out some air, and condensed water vapor in it assumed a curved shape as it moved towards "her". Narrator didn't speak, though.